# ios8 loading view from xib: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have very simple setup:

I have empty VC and `UIView` with UI in `xib`

MyView.m:

```
- (void) commonInit {
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
        self.bounds = self.view.bounds;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And my MyVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *bindings = @{@"myView": self.myView};
    [self.view addSubview:self.offlinePromoView];

    self.myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(topSpacing)-[myView]-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"topSpacing": @70} views:bindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
}
```

I want my subview to be padded 70 points from top and has the same width as controller's view. But I get:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x176ae8d0 MyView:0x176a7770.centerX == UIView:0x176a7840.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x176b10b0 MyView:0x176a7770.leading == UIView:0x176a7840.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x176b0900 UIView:0x176a7840.trailingMargin == MyView:0x176a7770.trailing>"
)
```

`0x176a7840` is `self.view` in my VC.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myView]-(-70)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
```

Comment: I understand that I can flush view to left and right side of superview, but I need to keep some spacing between them.

Comment: well maybe it should be in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(==70)-[view]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
```